# bootstrap 3 brand name middle nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a responsive site using bootstrap 3 with brand name middle in nav bar.  I want that two collapse bar in the two side of the nav bar. But I am facing problem. The left collapse bar is not adjusting with the logo it comes above the logo when I resize the window. Here is the image after implementing the code. [image: problem image]

HTML code :

```
</header>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered"> <img src="images/plogo.png">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>               
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

CSS Code :

```
 @media screen and (min-width:650px) {
.navbar-brand-centered {

    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;

}
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
    margin-left: -80px;
}


}
```

My main nav bar will be like this :

[image]

Can any one tell me how I customize nav like this ? I have plain html and css for my desired design but when I use them with bootstrap  position changes like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I could now recreate the issue, the problem is that you have way too much content on your navbar.
If you want everything to be shown in the navbar you have to either scale down your image or adjust the *container*'s width. That isn't too beautiful and may cause trouble if you use the container again.

But even if you do this, there are some cases (try to scale you window down a little more than mobile) in which the image still overlaps the Navbar Items!

If you want to create a **responsive** page, please code so the Site can adjust to any size, so you should allow the image to behave **responsive** and so scale down.

Simply add a `@media` rule to scale down the width of your `navbar-brand` and adjust it to center correctly by changing spacing rules like padding.

PS: I saw your Image isn't centered correctly, you should add a width to your navbar-brand and adjust the `margin-left` to half of the image's `width`.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question then, could you please set up a bootply so i can inspect your code better than with just the image?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/uSBwwb5Vpg please check it now. Please do not modify the logo size it should remain same as source.

Comment: I edited the answer, as it was way too much for a comment, please take a look!